Nested cross-validation results comparison based on adaptive thresholding
I am looking for a general thresholding mechanism that would allows me to sort out nested cross-validation results. Here is the problem statement:
Say I have a regression model Reg, a reference dataset D_ref of size S1, and candidate datasets Dc = {Dc_1, Dc_2, ..., Dc_n} all of size S2 (S2 > S1). Also, all datasets are dependent. Each configuration Reg x Dc_i is evaluated with a nested cross-validation where the inner loop optimizes hyper-parameters and the outer loop uses multiple train/test split over L loops. Each outer loop evaluates the model with a given metric and the final output of each nested cross-validation is the mean (mean(metric(Dc_i))) and standard deviation (std(metric(Dc_i))) of the metric, over the L loops, for the current Reg x Dc_i.
The goal is to only keep the candidate datasets Dc_i that increase the performances of the reference dataset D_ref. Here, i am looking for a threshold mechanism, instead of a pure statistical test, to be part of a general method (the general method actually build the datasets Dc_i but this is not relevant here). Also, even though threshold method and statistical tests are not so different, the thing is that some configuration may have small datasets, which limit the power of, say, a t-test.
At first, i used a naïve approach where threshold = mean(metric(Dc_ref)) and then only keeping the candidate datasets where mean(metric(Dc_i)) > threshold. But obviously this lead to false positives (false negative as well but this is not a concern here), which i know because i have access to the ground truth.
So, i am looking for a method where threshold would be something like threshold = mean(metric(Dc_ref)) + offset, or like threshold = coef * mean(metric(Dc_ref)), or any variation of that that would take into account how big the difference is between mean(metric(Dc_ref)) and mean(metric(Dc_i)), and how big are std(metric(.)), So that small improvement likely to be false positive are sorted out.
Note: I cannot access other data than mean(metric(.)) and std(metric(.)), first because It takes a very long time to run each Reg x Dc_i configuration and I did not saved other results (shame). But also because I need the method to be easily applied.
